# DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().InCategories() API Method not working as intended

Tags: kentico

I am trying to get documents of given type with assigned category. This is my code:

```
var inCategoryDocuments = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("XYZ.MyType").InCategories("CategoryCodeName");
```

It's result with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM View_CMS_Tree_Joined AS V WITH (NOLOCK, NOEXPAND) INNER JOIN xyz_MyType AS C WITH (NOLOCK) ON [V].[DocumentForeignKeyValue] = [C].[MyTypeID] AND V.ClassName = N'xyz.MyType' LEFT OUTER JOIN COM_SKU AS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON [V].[NodeSKUID] = [S].[SKUID] WHERE ([DocumentCulture] = N'en-EN' AND 0 = 1)
```

It looks like this API method (.InCategories()) doing nothing or I am missing something?

Kentico v11.0.26

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this category assigned to specific site? If so, it wouldn't work, because in your query you didn't specify the site from which you want get documents.

You can simply add

```
.OnCurrentSite()
```

to your DataQuery, it will look like this

```
var inCategoryDocuments = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("XYZ.MyType").OnCurrentSite().InCategories("CategoryCodeName");
```

It will retrieve the documents from the current website based on domain.

*IMO method .InCategory shouldn't take care about site or it should be parametrized.*

Comment: @Dawid it's due to the nature of how categories are setup. Categories can be global or site specific. Because Kentico supports multiple tenants, you need to look for site specific categories unless you are only using global categories. So that won't change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the using statement for it to work because those methods are extensions.

```
using CMS.DocumentEngine;
```

Comment: I have `using CMS.DocumentEngine;` statement on the top of the class, code compiles with success.